# Getting value from repeating HTML data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have repeating data that gets injected into the html like this:

```html
<div class="subFormContent" id="Results">

  <div class="subFormContentRow">
    <div class="subFormContentRowChildWrapper">
      <div id="subCtrlPreviewRow1-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewRowContainer">
        <div id="subCtrlRow1column1-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewCell">
          <div class="subCtrlPreviewCtrlHolder">
            <div class="control ">
              <label class="block label alignLabel">
                <span>value</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="textInput block field" id="value-identifier" value="value1" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="subCtrlRow1column2-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewCell">
          <div class="subCtrlPreviewCtrlHolder">
            <div class="control">
              <label class="block label alignLabel">
                <span>propName</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="textInput block field" id="propName-identifier" value="propname1" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

...Repeats

I need to get the value from column 1 where column 2 is equal to x with JavaScript or jquery, but it will not always be on the same row number. It will however only have one row where column 2 is x. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: use some convention to identify you stuff, i see you have some, so build the class name string

Comment: Can we see your JSFiddle on what you've tried so far?

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document.

Comment: @friedchicken879  I can see that this is your first posting to StackOverflow.  Welcome.  I will recommend that you review [some guidelines for posting questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Your question can certainly be improved.  You could provide a JSFiddle to show what you've tried. There are errors in your code that mess up formatting bad (Extra " s) You could show a screen print of the data screen with simple annotations. (if X here, then XYZ over there) to make it really clear what you are trying to achieve.  We don't want to discourage you, just make it better for all !

Comment: I have no control over the HTML that gets injected. This is what I have to work with. I haven't tried anything since I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

**updated for multiple rows**

**1.2 update if id's starts with words "value" and "propName"**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 5,
      row = $('.subFormContentRow');
  
  row.each(function(index, el){
   var  inputProp = $(el).find('[id^="propName"]'),
        inputVal = $(el).find('[id^="value"]');
        if(inputProp.val() == x){
          alert(inputVal.val());
        }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subFormContent" id="Results">

<div class="subFormContentRow">
  <div class="subFormContentRowChildWrapper">
    <div id="subCtrlPreviewRow1-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewRowContainer">
      <div id="subCtrlRow1column1-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewCell">
        <div class="subCtrlPreviewCtrlHolder">
          <div class="control">
            <label class="block label alignLabel">
            <span>value</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="textInput block field" id="value-456456456" value="value1" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="subCtrlRow1column2-identifier" class="subCtrlPreviewCell">
        <div class="subCtrlPreviewCtrlHolder">
          <div class="control">
            <label class="block label alignLabel">
            <span>propName</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="textInput block field" id="propName-45647898778645656" value="5" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know the question is poorly written, but the author did say he had multiple rows, even though he only shows one row.  Your jQuery is looking at an ID, not a class.  How is that going to work in a finished product with multiple lines of code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to change the HTML, I'm forced to use it as is. Also the ids for propName and value gets a GUID like identifier added to it, so it looks like id=propName-9f87b1d3-6f62-474d-9259-960046502ed9.

Comment: id starts word propName ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be using ids in a way that they show up multiple times on the page.
You can still do it by finding the element, traversing back up to the row, then finding the value.

With JQuery:

```
$("#propName[value='" + x + "']")
    .closest(".subFormContentRow").find("#value").val();
```